# Facing Nullpointer while uploading multiple files via multithreading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, autowired

I am trying to upload multiple file data to a database using multiple threads.

#### Controller layer

```
System.out.println("saveStudent");
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new FileHandlerClass("test" + i + ".csv"));
    t.start();
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class FileHandlerClass
    implements Runnable
{
    public FileHandlerClass()
    {
    }

    @Autowired
    private SpringbootService service;
    private String fileName;

    public FileHandlerClass(String fileName)
    {
        System.out.println(fileName);
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        this.service.saveStudent(this.fileName); // Facing nullpointer exception here
    }
}
```

But I get a null pointer exception at
`this.service.saveStudent(this.fileName)`; .

[image]

How can I fix it?

Removing @Autowired works, but I don't know why it is not initialising the bean while doing with the above code.

```
private SpringbootService service;
private String fileName;

public FileHandlerClass(String fileName, SpringbootService service)
{
    System.out.println(fileName);
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.service = service;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    service.saveStudent(this.fileName);
}
```

Comment: Could you post code of the method ```this.service.saveStudent(this.fileName)```?

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing `service`, thus when you call `this.service.saveStudent(this.fileName)` you're getting `NullPointerException`. See Peasant's answer on why the `@Autowired` is not working.

Also, general tip: 
I'd remove the following constructor:

```
public FileHandlerClass()
{

}
```

as that can introduce a scenario where `fileName` is null, which would also cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: but i have already added @autowired on SpringbootService, so i think it should initialize of its own

Comment: Can you add System.out.println(this.service) in run() to check if it is null?

Comment: yes it is coming as null, but why ?, do you have any idea

Comment: if we pass the service reference in constructor, then its working

Comment: Can you provide more information on the setup of your project? More information on the SpringbootService class?

Comment: Responding to your comment, how are you getting the service instance in the first place (which you are then passing in the constructor)?

Comment: by using @Autowired
    private SpringbootService springbootService; in controller layer

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not initialized because you create `FileHandlerClass` using `new`.
You've annotated your FileHandlerClass as a `@Component`, and service field as `@Autowired`. So if your `SpringbootService` is also a component (service, repository, .....) just instantiate `FileHandlerClass` in a "spring way", for example, by using the `ApplicationContext`, and it will autowire the service.

And one more thing. Spring's `@Component` is a singletone by default. So if you want to create several instances you should point the `@Scope`, for example:

```
@Scope("prototype")
```

For more information about how it works you can read 
[spring core documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core%60enter%20code%20here%60)